How to unhide the hidden columns in pandas?
How to unhide the hidden columns in pandas? Actually my dataframe containes 24 columns, because of many columns if in python columns are hidding, please give some suggestions on this how to view all the columns?
i tried to check the columns by   df.columns
Index(['id', 'address_state', 'application_type', 'emp_length', 'emp_title',
'grade', 'home_ownership', 'issue_date', 'last_credit_pull_date',
'last_payment_date', 'loan_status', 'next_payment_date', 'member_id',
'purpose', 'sub_grade', 'term', 'verification_status', 'annual_income',
'dti', 'installment', 'int_rate', 'loan_amount', 'total_acc',
'total_payment'],
dtype='object')

pd.options.display.max_columns = None

Thank you so much for your answer, it works
